# Windows Driver substitue for linux device driver sysfs interface

Tags: windows, device-driver, sysfs, wdm, wdf

Let me describe what sysfs does : its a pseudo file system where files, directories are generated by the core kernel or kernel drivers. And these files have read/write access and are a mechanism to control certain kernel level parameters by user space (seperate from ioctls and file operations).

1. [Sysfs from Kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/sysfs.html)
2. [Sysfs from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs)

The following is an example of how userspace interacts with sysfs.

```
    $ cat /sys/modules/mydriver/foo_count
    1 
    $ echo "2" > /sys/modules/mydriver/foo_count  $ cat /sys/modules/mydriver/foo_count
    2
```

The `cat` command will trigger a read via the `show_foo_count()` kernel routine, while the `echo` will trigger a write via the `store_foo_count()` routine

The following is how the kernel driver/module might intercept the user space activity.

```
static ssize_t show_foo_count(struct kobject *kobj,struct kobj_attribute *attr,
                                  char *buf)
{
    /* This will perform a read operation and contents of buf will be updated*/
    ...
}
static ssize_t store_foo_count(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr,
                               const char *buf,size_t len)
{
    /* Contents are read from buf and stored within the driver's context/state */
    ...

}
```

[A good example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776495/writing-a-sysfs-module)

**How can one achieve the same sysfs usage on windows drivers ?**

I see the following windows concepts, but I am unable to map them to be the equivalent of syfs :

A. [Device Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_device_object)

B. [File Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdfdevice/ns-wdfdevice-_wdf_fileobject_config)

Comment: Windows Projected File System

Comment: Looks interesting, it may solve part of my problem :)